# pulseaudio: use both hdmi (stereo) and 5.1 simultaneously

Tags: debian, audio, nvidia, pulseaudio

I have a 5.1 audio system, and i'm using a tv as monitor , my tv connects to my nvidia gtx 1060 using HDMI and my 5.1 system to the mobo's sound card analog output.   I can successfully configure my audio system as 5.1 (surround)separately and i can use my HDMI as stereo separately . I installed paprefs to enable simultaneous output ,restarted pulseaudio and enabled HDMI and 5.1 output , but the problem is it only enables stereo so i lose my 5.1 system surround capabilities . How can i configure so i have my 5.1 surround enabled, and tv speakers as stereo?

Comment: How is your 5.1 audio system connected? Does the PC HDMI go to the audio system, and is then forwarded to the TV? Are both the TV and the audio system conneceted to the PC (2 HDMI cables)? Something else?

Comment: Basically its 2 connections: 
1) Tv connected as monitor to Nvidia GTX card
2) 5.1 system connected to motherboard's analog audio card

Right now i can have both simultaneous but only in stero config, 5.1 system just have left/right channels, and  i want to configure surround on 5.1 system, and stereo on tv output.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at what `paprefs` does, but the way I'd do it use to add a virtual sink ("null sink") you use as target for the simultanious output

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=simul sink_properties=device.description=SimultaniousOutput
```

and then loopback twice from the `.monitor` source to the sinks you need

```
pacmd load-module module-loopback source=simul.monitor sink="name_of_51_system_sink"
pacmd load-module module-loopback source=simul.monitor sink="name_of_tv_sink"
```

where you can get the names of the sinks with

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
```

(omit the angular brackets). Then I'd cross my fingers that the loopback already handles conversion from 5.1 to stereo; if not, I'd go look up the module arguments [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/) and fiddle with the format parameters until it works.

Once it works, integrate into Pulseaudio startup files.

**Edit**

It looks like `paprefs` uses the `combine-sink` module, so something like

```
pacmd load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combine sink_properties=device.description=myCombine slaves=sink1,sink2[,...] channels=6
```

is also worth a try, though I don't know if it will work of the slave sinks only support a different number of channels.

Comment: After fiddling around with virtual alsa devices for 8h without any success (besides crashing pulseaudio) your approach finally worked +1